# SQL Presto - How to convert dates into quarter/year format?

Tags: sql, date, format, presto

I have a dates that I need to aggregate into quarter/year format in SQL Presto. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) is your friend - use either [`date_trunc`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#truncation-function) with corresponding unit, or [extraction functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#extraction-function) (`year`, `quarter`):

```sql
select date_trunc('quarter', now())
    , date_trunc('year', now()) 
    , quarter(now())
    , year(now())
```

Sample output:

| _col0 | _col1 | _col2 | _col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 UTC | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC | 3 | 2022 |